# C++ friend template that use SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, friend

This is a simple question in fact. I have a template class with one parameter.
In an other object, I make it a friend of it, like this :

```
template< typename type_t >
class A
{
    ...
}

template< typename type_t >
class B
{
    template< typename >
    friend class A; // Works fine !

    ...
}
```

After that, I wanted to add a condition to discard integral number when instancing the class A (and B by the way), by doing this :

```
template< typename type_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v< type_t >, bool > = false >
class A
{
    ...
}

template< typename type_t, std::enable_if_t< std::is_floating_point_v< type_t >, bool > = false >
class B
{
    template< typename >
    friend class A; // ============> Error!

    ...
}
```

By reading the compiler message, I understood the template now has two parameters. But what should I put to the second parameter when I'm friending the class ? I tried template< typename, typename >, template< typename, bool > and template< typename, true >... All fails to compile.

What is the solution here ?

Comment: The use of `enable_if` seems misguided to me. SFINAE is useful for the situation where we consider multiple candidates for something (overloads or class template specializations) and try to choose the correct one, without causing compilation to fail. You don't seem to be doing that, you seem to be after a hard error. A static assertion would serve this purpose much better.

Comment: By rethinking about the design, in my code only the class B must avoid integral numbers. The class A is only a tool to work on class B. There is no point for class A to manipulate integers as well, but it will never do this, because of B. I think I try to be over-protective...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As StoryTeller said in the comments, a `static_assert` inside the class `B` or `A` might be a simpler solution. It will not use a second template parameter and will enable the familiar friend declaration.

However, if you still want to go through the SFINAE way, you can declare your friend using the full SFINAE expression in it:

```
template<typename type_t, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<type_t>, bool> = false>
class B
{
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool>>
    friend class A;
};
```